# List<object> always returns 1 as it's count

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have created a list and the count always returns 1. When I view the objects properties (mi), I can see that all of the values I have retrieved are in fact there. So I know the DB part works and I am reading data back

When I try to get the value from the list index, it will only allow me to access the first item (0). Its as if it has counted the object I have added to the list as one value, even though in debug , the values are itemised.

The strange thing is it, it shows values of the object items (MeterId, MeterType etc...).

The values are there but they don't seem to have any index. I am trying to assign the values by using:

```
           var mylist = GetMeterInfo.GetMeterInformation(MeterId);
            var mid= mylist[0];
            var mid1 = mylist[1];
            var mid2 = mylist[2];
```

But it fails when I try assigning 'myList[1]' with an out of index error, because there is no index greater than 0 . Even when I look at "myList" I can see all of the 10 values there, but I cannot get to them.

```
public static List<MeterInformation> GetMeterInformation(int MeterId)       {
        string SqlQuery = "*************"
        SqlConnection conn = null;
        SqlCommand cmd = null;
        SqlDataReader rd = null;

        conn = new SqlConnection(Connections.Conns.CS);
        cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlQuery, conn);

        conn.Open();
        rd = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 List<MeterInformation> MeterInfo = new List<MeterInformation>();           

        while (rd.Read()) {
            MeterInformation mi = new MeterInformation();
            mi.MeterId = rd.GetInt32(0);
            mi.MeterType = rd.GetString(1);
            mi.MeterName = rd.GetString(2);
            mi.MeterDescription = rd.GetString(3);
            mi.MeterSerial = rd.GetString(4);
            mi.MeterMPAN = rd.GetString(5);
            mi.MeterCreatedOn = rd.GetDateTime(6);
            mi.MeterLocation = rd.GetString(7);
            mi.MeterBuilding = rd.GetString(8);
            mi.MeterSite = rd.GetString(9);

            MeterInfo.Add(mi);
        }

        conn.Close();
        conn.Dispose();

        return MeterInfo;
```

Any pointers, I have run out of ideas...

Comment: Move `MeterInformation mi = new MeterInformation();` inside the `while` loop

Comment: you are adding the same MeterInformation  over and over; create new ones inside the while loop; but if there is only one in the db there will be only one in the list

Comment: you really should not have edited your question (#3) to fix the fault... all the answers are redundant.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions Meirion?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating a single `MeterInformation` object and you keep adding the same object to the list.

In the loop, you are simply modifying that single object and adding another reference of it to the list.

So, if you loop 5 times, the output would be a list that contains 5 references to the same `MeterInformation` object that has the information of the last row queried from the database.

To fix the problem, move this line inside the `while` loop:

```
MeterInformation mi = new MeterInformation();
```

This will make sure that you create a new `MeterInformation` object for each row in the result set.

**UPDATE:**

Trying to understand your problem again, I think that you should expect to get a single record from the database since your are retrieving a specific *Meter* (using a specific ID). I guess that your SQL query targets a specific record.

Your confusion should be cleared if you understand that `MeterId`, `MeterType`, `MeterName` ...etc are properties of a single object.

So to access them you can do this:

```
var record = GetMeterInfo.GetMeterInformation(MeterId)[0];

var id = record.MeterId;

var type = record.MeterType;

var name = record.MeterName;
```

If fact, since you expect the method to return a single item, you should not return a `List`, but instead return a `MeterInformation` like this:

```
public static MeterInformation GetMeterInformation(int MeterId)
{
    //...

    rd.Read();

    MeterInformation mi = new MeterInformation();
    mi.MeterId = rd.GetInt32(0);
    mi.MeterType = rd.GetString(1);
    mi.MeterName = rd.GetString(2);
    mi.MeterDescription = rd.GetString(3);
    mi.MeterSerial = rd.GetString(4);
    mi.MeterMPAN = rd.GetString(5);
    mi.MeterCreatedOn = rd.GetDateTime(6);
    mi.MeterLocation = rd.GetString(7);
    mi.MeterBuilding = rd.GetString(8);
    mi.MeterSite = rd.GetString(9);

    MeterInfo.Add(mi);

    //...

    return mi;
}
```

And use it like this:

```
var record = GetMeterInfo.GetMeterInformation(MeterId);

var id = record.MeterId;

var type = record.MeterType;

var name = record.MeterName;
```

Comment: I have tried adding the line inside the loop and I still get 1 as the count. I have added the full declaration in my code above in case there is something you may notice in there.

Comment: What is the SQL query that your are executing? How do you know that it is not returning only one record? Try to execute it in some SQL client (like SQL Management Studio if you are working with SQL Server) and see how much records you have.

Comment: I tested the query in SQL Server and it works. I have also debugged the datareader and the 'mi' object and they return the values I am expecting. All of the values are there in the 'return MeterInfo;' but the count is 1 and the index is zero.

Answer (score 2):

Move `mi` creation in while loop, because you are changing and trying to add same object constantly.

```
    while (rd.Read()) {
        MeterInformation mi = new MeterInformation();
        mi.MeterId = rd.GetInt32(0);
        mi.MeterType = rd.GetString(1);
        mi.MeterName = rd.GetString(2);
        mi.MeterDescription = rd.GetString(3);
        mi.MeterSerial = rd.GetString(4);
        mi.MeterMPAN = rd.GetString(5);
        mi.MeterCreatedOn = rd.GetDateTime(6);
        mi.MeterLocation = rd.GetString(7);
        mi.MeterBuilding = rd.GetString(8);
        mi.MeterSite = rd.GetString(9);

        MeterInfo.Add(mi);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

How about the following?  Moved the mi into the while block.

```
var MeterInfo = new List<MeterInformation>();
using(var conn = new SqlConnection(Connections.Conns.CS))
{
    using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlQuery, conn))
    {
        conn.Open();
        using (var rd = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (rd.Read()) {
                var mi = new MeterInformation();
                mi.MeterId = rd.GetInt32(0);
                mi.MeterType = rd.GetString(1);
                mi.MeterName = rd.GetString(2);
                mi.MeterDescription = rd.GetString(3);
                mi.MeterSerial = rd.GetString(4);
                mi.MeterMPAN = rd.GetString(5);
                mi.MeterCreatedOn = rd.GetDateTime(6);
                mi.MeterLocation = rd.GetString(7);
                mi.MeterBuilding = rd.GetString(8);
                mi.MeterSite = rd.GetString(9);

                MeterInfo.Add(mi);
            }
        }
    }
}  
return MeterInfo;
```

Comment: As I mentioned to Yacoubs post, it still returns one. I have added the full code above. It's really odd.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to be clever, I just made the list List. I asked a buddy of mine and as you all say it is passing the entire object as one thing.